# Append to Ansible dictionary in group_vars without hash_behaviour = merge

Tags: ansible

I want to define a dictionary variable that various host groups can add their own keys to *in group_vars* (not using `set_fact`). E.g. something like this:

group_vars\ftp_servers.yml:

```
important_ports:
    ftp: 21
```

group_vars\web_servers.yml:

```
important_ports:
    http: 80
```

so that when run on a server with both of these roles the dictionary is combined, i.e. `important_ports` =

```
{
    ftp: 21,
    http: 80
}
```

This is exactly what `hash_behaviour = merge` does, but it's [deprecated and will be removed in Ansible 2.13](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/63300). How do I achieve the same thing without that?

The only solution I've seen recommended is to use the `combine` filter:

```
set_fact:
  important_ports: "{{ important_ports | combine({ http: 80 }) }}"
```

This works in a `set_fact` task, but fails in group_vars with "**recursive loop detected in template string: {{ important_ports | combine({ http: 80 }) }}**"

I even tried initialising the variable to empty dictionary (`important_ports: {}`) in **group_vars/all**, which is supposed to be evaluated before other group_vars, but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 5):

A (not so clean...) possible solution to this specific problem. This is based on convention where you use the group name in the var name for specific group ports.

Note that if you redefine the same port name with a different value, the latest loaded group will win.

Given the following all-in-one inventory placed in `inventories/mergegroups/hosts.yml`

```yaml
---
all:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: local
    important_ports: >-
      {%- set result={} -%}
      {%- for group in groups -%}
      {{ result.update(lookup('vars', group + '_important_ports', default={})) }}
      {%- endfor -%}
      {{ result }}

ftp_servers:
  vars:
    ftp_servers_important_ports:
      ftp: 21
  hosts:
    a:
    b:

web_servers:
  vars:
    web_servers_important_ports:
      http: 80
  hosts:
    a:

other_group:
  vars:
    other_group_important_ports:
      mysql: 3306
  hosts:
    a:
    b:

no_port_group:
  # as you can see no port definition here.
  hosts:
    a:
    b:
    c:
```

We get the following results for the 3 different host:

```sh
$ ansible -i inventories/mergegroups/ a -m debug -a msg="{{ important_ports }}"
a | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": {
        "ftp": 21,
        "http": 80,
        "mysql": 3306
    }
}
$ ansible -i inventories/mergegroups/ b -m debug -a msg="{{ important_ports }}"
b | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": {
        "ftp": 21,
        "mysql": 3306
    }
}
$ ansible -i inventories/mergegroups/ c -m debug -a msg="{{ important_ports }}"
c | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that should work, I guess, but as you say, it's not exactly a clean solution. It breaks easily and silently if a group gets renamed, for example.

Comment: Didn't know you can use template in inventory! Nice and also yuck :-)