# Ansible: accessing group var variable information without inheritance

Tags: ansible

I have a server that is a member of groups a, b, and c (and d, e, f... etc). There are possibly 3 group_var files (or more if the individual group_vars are directories rather than files).

```yaml
# group_vars/a.yml
foo: 1
```

```yaml
# group_vars/b.yml
foo: 2
```

```yaml
# group_vars/c.yml
foo: 3
```

```ini
# inventory
[a]
wibble

[b]
wibble

[c]
wibble

[d]
wibble
...
```

Ultimately I wish for host wibble to have a variable `foo_list: [1,2,3]`. There was some [talk on GitHub](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17714) about this functionality but it seemed to fizzle out unfortunately. So with that in mind, I want to be able to recreate the functionality using vanilla Ansible, whereby I pluck out all the values of a variable that the hostvar could possibly have been before inheritance squashed it into one value. To do this, I need access to something like groupvars[group_name], but I cannot find if this feature exists, and I cannot find it documented anywhere and all the obvious places I'm looking have been unfruitful. Is this functionality available at all in Ansible?

For my purposes the ordering of foo_list is unimportant.

Alternatively if someone can think of a cute alternative to what I've asked above, I'm open to learning. For example I'm not against setting variables foo_a, foo_b, foo_c in the respective group_vars, and building foo_list that way.

Comment: There's no easy and clean way but I once propose [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62814549/9401096). I won't mark your question as duplicate since 1) I'm the author of the answer 2) my answer wasn't (yet) accepted. 3) others may have better ideas to share.

Comment: @Zeitounator well done for ingenuity but I'm sadly in agreement that it doesn't look like a nice way of doing it at all!

Comment: To me it seems so obvious that there should be a groupvars[groupname] I'm surprised I haven't found it let alone it might not exist.

Comment: You're welcome to propose a feature request and even a PR to the ansible team. But you should take time to read some project/ticket literature before you do so because the subject is far from being that easy. It's also quite easy to live without this once you know that limitation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, and a [PR on Github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22559) was closed as being too difficult to implement.